# Wrong inflection points

Tags: python, numpy

I want to come up with a plot that shows the inflection points of a curve as follows:

[image]

I have a somewhat similar curve and I want to compute somehow the inflection points by using `python`. My curve looks as follows:

[image]

I am using the following code to compute the inflection points:

```
def find_inflection_points(df, n=1):
        
    raw = df['consumption'].to_numpy()
    
    infls = []
    dx = 0
    for i, x in enumerate(np.diff(raw, n)):
        if x >= dx and i > 0:
            infls.append(i*n)
        dx = x

    # plot results
    plt.plot(raw, label='Input Data')
    for i, infl in enumerate(infls, 1):
        plt.axvline(x=infl, color='k', label=f'Inflection Point {i}')
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.55, 1.0))
    
    return infls
```

However, I am getting the following plot:

[image]

I would expect less inflection points. Any idea of what should I change or any other proposal for implementation?

EDIT:

The data is the following:

```
raw = np.array([52.33,
 50.154444444444444,
 48.69222222222223,
 46.49111111111111,
 44.01444444444444,
 43.30555555555556,
 43.034444444444446,
 40.62888888888889,
 40.38111111111111,
 39.07666666666667,
 38.339999999999996,
 36.41444444444445,
 36.37888888888889,
 36.17111111111111,
 35.666666666666664,
 33.827777777777776,
 29.35222222222222,
 28.60888888888889,
 24.43,
 22.078888888888887,
 21.756666666666664,
 20.345555555555556,
 19.874444444444446,
 19.763333333333335])
```

Comment: I think inflection points are the ones where x != dx.  you are only checking when `x >= dx`   (should be x > dx instead). Then add another condition when `x < dx`  As you see you are only detecting concave points and missing the convex ones.

Comment: I have the feeling that you don't really use the words "inflection points" knowing exactly what they are. On your 1st example, those are not inflection points, but just points of discontinuity in the first derivative. 3 of them happen to be also inflection points, but the 3rd is not, and there are some inflection points that are not there.

Comment: Whereas in your code, you are not looking for inflection point, nor for those slope discontinuities. But apparently for any points where the downward slope is reduced.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki : addiing those would make all points "inflection points", except for those in a strictly straight line slope.

Comment: So, before we (as least I) answer, be more specific on what you are looking for. Are you looking for inflection points? (points where there is a turnout in the 1st derivative, that is, assuming everything is differentiable, where second derivative is 0. Or, with a broader definition, whose left limit of first derivative and right limit have different signs). Or are you looking for points with sharp change of slope?

Comment: And also, do you need some sort of tolerance, under which a point is not considered to be an inflection point (whatever definition you retain). Apparently yes, since you were asking for a reduction of the number of inflection points (even tho those are not the points you are probably looking for, it at least proves that you were willing to decimate the list). Maybe, to avoid a XY problem here, it would be better if you say (in just a few words. We don't really need the whole context) what those curve are, and what information you're trying to get from them.

Comment: @chrslg The first plot is from a paper that mentions these points as inflection points, although as you mentioned not all of them are inflection points with the mathematical definition. These curves are called load duration curves and they depict an electrical system’s demand, in units of power versus the percentage of the time for which this load or a load is greater than it existed. The inflection points according to the paper indicate points on a curve at which the sign of the curvature changes, therefore indicating a behavioural change in load consumption in this case.

Comment: Yes, that is another definition of "inflection points". So they are inflection points after all. Well, sort of. Because depending on the size of the magnifier you use to look at the curve (strictly speaking, we use an infinite one in maths; but with real data, you never do so) the 3rd one is not. Or, said otherwise, if you look at a scale for which the 3rd one is an inflection point, then, there are many others that are not shown. But, well, definition is the one of inflection points. And after all, it is never easy to judge from a drawing.

Comment: You haven't replied about the tolerance. But I take there has to be one, since, as I said, the example from the paper you've referred is obviously using one.

Comment: Also, it would be easier with some data. Is the size of `raw` really to be to be included in a single line `raw=np.array([...,...,...])` in your question code?

Comment: @chrslg I edited the post with the suitable information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, strictly speaking, inflection point is indeed a change of sign of curvature. Which, for a 3 times differenciable function, is a point at which there is a change of sign of the 2nd derivative (the second derivative is 0, and the third derivative is not).

In your case, since the data are very discrete (only 24 data, one per hour in the day, I surmise), it is quite tricky to talk about second and third derivative. But if we give a try, we can see that, not only the point you are interested in are not inflection points (when the second derivative is 0, that means that the first derivative is locally constant. Which means that the slope is constant. And the points you seem to be interested in are, on the contrary, points where there is a change of slope. The the opposite of an inflection point!.

They are tho, inflection points of the derivative, since it seems that they are local extremum of the second derivative, so, at least if we had a continuous enough curve to dare speak of 3rd derivative, one could that that the extrema of second derivative are the 0 of the 3rd derivative. And 3rd derivative is the 2nd derivative of the 1st derivative. So, you could say that you are interested in the inflection points of the 1st derivative, that is of the slope.

See code below:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

raw = np.array([52.33, 50.154444444444444, 48.69222222222223, 46.49111111111111, 44.01444444444444, 43.30555555555556, 43.034444444444446, 40.62888888888889, 40.38111111111111, 39.07666666666667, 38.339999999999996, 36.41444444444445, 36.37888888888889, 36.17111111111111, 35.666666666666664, 33.827777777777776, 29.35222222222222, 28.60888888888889, 24.43, 22.078888888888887, 21.756666666666664, 20.345555555555556, 19.874444444444446, 19.763333333333335])
x=np.arange(24)

rawb=np.roll(raw, 1)
rawa=np.roll(raw,-1)


der2=rawb+rawa-2*raw
der2[0]=der2[-1]=np.nan
der2abs=np.abs(der2)
offs = der2abs/(der2abs+np.roll(der2abs, -1))
yoffs = raw*(1-offs) + rawa*offs
chsign=(der2*np.roll(der2,-1))<0


s=1.5
mxder2 = (((der2>np.roll(der2,-1)) & (der2>np.roll(der2,1))) | ((der2<np.roll(der2,-1)) & (der2<np.roll(der2,1)))) & (der2abs>s)

fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax2=ax.twinx()

ax.plot(raw)
ax2.plot([0]*24)
ax2.plot(der2)

ax.scatter(x[mxder2], raw[mxder2], 80, c='r', marker='*')
ax.scatter((x+offs)[chsign], yoffs[chsign], 30, c='g', marker='o')
plt.show()
```

It shows
[image]

The blue line are your data.
The orange line is the second derivative.
The green dots are the points where second derivative is 0.
While the red stars are the points where second derivative is an extrema (with a minimum absolute value: we don't count local extrema of area where second derivative is almost flatlining 0).

From what you have shown, you seem more interested in red stars!
The green dots are not just too numerous. Even filtering them (from an unknown criteria) would not do: they are all quite boring!

What makes the situation, and the vocabulary, ambiguous is the fact that we are talking about discrete points in reality. Inflection point are points where second derivative is 0. That is where 1st derivative is an extrema. And you need on the contrary points where second derivative is extreme. On so discrete set of data, you can be both tho. And maybe that was the case in your paper: points with sharp change of slopes are points where second derivative are extremely positive, but is surronded by 2 extremely negative second derivative (or the opposite).

But, my point is, you seem more interested in red stars.

As for how I compute that:
`der2` is the second derivative, using discrete scheme `y[-dt]-2y[0]+y[dt]`
`der2abs` is its absolute value.
`offs` is a barycenter weighted by successive values of `der2abs`. Where there is a change of sign of the 2nd derivative, between index i and i+1, this account for an estimation of the exact position of the 0: offs is 0 if the 0 is at index i, 1 if it is at index 1, 0.5 if it is in the middle between i and i+1, etc.  `offs` makes no sense where there is no change of sign (and we won't use those values).
`yoffs` is the raw value using the same barycenter. So, yoffs is `yoffs[i]`, `yoffs[i+1]`, `yoffs[i+0.5]` in the 3 previous cases (what would be `yoffs[i+0.5]` were a legal thing).  Like `offs`, makes sense only where there is a change of sign of `der2`.
`chsign` is precisely what says where those change of sign occur.

So, we just have to plot `yoffs[chsign]` vs `(x+offs)[chsign]` to filter the cases where the second derivative are 0.

The red stars are easier to compute:
We just find all the points whose second derivative is either bigger or smaller than its 2 neighbor. And filter those to add a minimum value condition (|secondDerivative| must be at least 1.5)

Comment: How did you come up with `s=1.5`?

Comment: @Kosmylo no magic here. There are 14 extrema. That seemed too much. So I filtered the biggest one. `s=1` was letting some too flat looking ones. `s=2` was filtering out some quite sharp angles. So `s=1.5` won.